# Generalized spin connection and dreibein in higher spin gravity

Tags: gravity, string-theory, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, higher-spin

I am studying **3D higher spin gravity** and I would like to know the mathematical and physical meaning of generalized [spin connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection) and generalized [dreibein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_formalism_%28physics%29) that appear in this theory. It is well known that there are important connections between **higher spin theories** and **string theory**.

> 1. For this reason I am wondering if the generalized spin connection is related or not to the parallel transport of extended objects (strings, membranes, etc.) on compact manifolds?
> 2. Is there also a relation with Hitchin's [generalized geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_complex_structure)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me say that there is nothing perculiar about 3d HS theories - I mean the Vasiliev equations look exactly the same as in any other dimension.

The starting point in HS theory is to gauge HS algebra, so the generalized spin-connection and generalized dreibeins are just particular components of a single connection of a HS algebra. Connection of a HS algebra is just usual Yang-Mills connection, but the algebra is not $su(n)$ but something usually infinite-dimensional.

Some explanation comes from gravity which, as is known, can be reformulated as a gauge theory of Poincare, de Sitter or anti-de Sitter algebra. Again, vielbein and spin-connection are particular components of a connection of one of the above mentioned algebras.

HS algebras are infinite-dimensional (I ignore $sl(n)$ that was considered by many people in $3d$ since it is not a part of a consistent HS theory --- one can take $sl(n)$ Chern-Simons, of course, but it is not a full HS theor). Hence the space they act geometrically is infinite-dimensional as well and because of that it is not a well-studied topic.

Therefore, to both of your questions I would answer no and no.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, my questions were related to sl(n) Chern-Simons theories that look quite self-consistent even if you say that they do not represent a full HS theory. I am wondering what is the physical meaning of generalized spin connection in this particular context.

Comment: Ok, then it is not exactly about HS theory and related ads/cft duality, which requires matter fields to be present in a theory and they cannot couple to sl(n) Chern-Simons. You probably need to google higher teichmuller theory, which is a way to talk about sl(n) structures